# How to pass a dynamic object of the type array to a function?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to pass a dynamic size standard and of typename type array to a function.

I can't figure out how to do it. Why can't I just accept a reference to the object array?

The code I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void showArrays(void *myArrayPointer, int size, T type) {
    array<T, size> myArray = myArrayPointer;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << myArray.at(i) << " \n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    array<int,6> myArray = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 };
    cout << "The array is \n";
    showArrays(&myArray,6,0);

    return 0;
}
```

But I get expected compile-time constant expression for the Size still.
My function header is also not very pretty. But I couldn't figure out a way to have the size dynamic without passing a generic pointer or creating a template of the class array where the size is an attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a function template where the type is a template parameter, but the size is a runtime property (which could make sense if you want to avoid binary bloat), then you want something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void showArrays(T* p, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cout << p[i] << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    std::array<int, 6> myArray = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 };
    std::cout << "The array is \n";
    showArrays(myArray.data(), 6);  // or use myArray.size()
}
```

You can reuse your template for other kinds of contiguous arrays, too:

```
float a[] = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 };
showArrays(a, 4);        // full array
showArrays(a + 1, 2);    // just the middle two

std::vector<long> v = /* ... */;
showArrays(v.data(), v.size());

std::string s = "hello world";
showArrays(s.data() + 6, 5);
```

Note that `T` is a *template* parameter and not a function parameter. Note further that we never specify an argument for the parameter: that's because the argument is *deduced*. If you did want to pass a void pointer, like you did in your example, then you would not be able to deduce the template argument from the function call, and you'd have to specify it explicitly:

```
template <typename T>
void showArrays(void* p, int n) {
//              ^^^^^
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cout << static_cast<T*>(p)[i] << '\n';
        //           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        //           cast to object pointer,
        //           note that "T" shows up in your code now!
    }
}

showArrays<int>(myArray.data(), myArray.size());
//        ^^^^^
//        explicit template argument
```

Comment: This is the right answer. I couldn't figure out what he was trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

There is no reason to use a `void*` here at all.  The type of the elements and size of a `std::array` are known at compile time and you can capture those using a template.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void print_arry(const std::array<T, N>& arr)
{
    for (const auto& e : arr)
        std::cout << e << "\n";
}
```

Will capture any `std::array` and print its elements as long as they have an overloaded `operator <<`.  You can also use `T` as the element type and `N` as the size of the array inside the function which lets you write a accumulate function like

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
T print_arry(const std::array<T, N>& arr)
{
    if (N == 0)
        return 0;
    T accum = arr[0];
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i < N; ++i)
        accum += arr[i];
    return accum;
}
```